# Ripping Wii games in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: games, dvd, wii

I want a straightforward way to rip my Wii games and store them as .iso files on my computer. I am not knowledgeable with DD, as I mostly use the graphical interface to save time and sanity. Is there any good tool to rip Wii games WITHOUT DD? I've already tried an outdated solution with Sonic Colors, but it didn't recognize my disk drive. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

I am going to recommend you the easiest way I have found to copy anything. I'll teach you DD and it will be fun:

first go to your home:

```
cd ~
cd Documents
```

First look to see which device you DVD is on run

```
lsscsi
```

if it's not installed run:

```
sudo apt-get install lsscsi
lsscsi
```

see which /dev/s** device says DVD or cd or optical

now type the following:

```
sudo dd bs=4k if=/dev/s** of=Game.iso
```

now close your terminal go to your documents and have fun

dd options

```
bs is the block size. you can skip if you want.
of= output file. where data comes from
if= input file. Where is your data going?
```

Comment: I assume you meant "dev/snd"? I think the servers decided to censor it for no reason. XD

Comment: Never mind. You were using the *s as placeholders. XD